# jquery mousemove not working correctly

Tags: jquery, event-handling, mousemove

I have to make something like when user moves the mouse something shows up and after two seconds it hides **(like [flickr slideshow](http://www.flickr.com/photos/eddielaw/sets/72157603487858748/show/))**. I use jquery `.mousemove` event with `slideDown and slideUp`. While calling `slides functions` I also pass a callback function which hides it after 2 seconds.

**Problem**: On first mouse move it shows up and then after 2 seconds it hides. But after that on mouse move it is showing up only once in 1000. Why?

**jquery code**:

```
var prevDate = 0; // keep this as a global variable 

$('#slides').mousemove(function(e) {
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    if(date - prevDate > 300){
        $('#up').slideDown('normal',function (){
            $('#up').delay(2000).slideUp('normal');
        });
        $('#down').slideDown('normal',function (){
            $('#down').delay(2000).slideUp('normal');
        });
            prevDate = date;
    }
});
```

Where slides is a div with width and height 100% and `#up and #down` are two divs which i want to show and hide.

you can see the whole code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/knoxxs/3rZMM/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At last I've understood what you are trying to do after seeing the fickr link you provided**

---

You want to show both the top and bottom panel whenever the `mouse moves` and keep showing the panels **while** the mouse is moving. Then you want to **hide them exactly 2 seconds after the mouse STOPs moving**.

Now here is the solution:

```
$("document").ready(function(e) {
    var onmousestop = function() {
        $('#up').slideUp('normal');
        $('#down').slideUp('normal');
    };    
    var timer;    
    $('#slides').mousemove(function(e) {
        $('#up').slideDown('normal');
        $('#down').slideDown('normal');
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(onmousestop, 2000);
    });
});​
```

Also find the solution in http://jsfiddle.net/3rZMM/9/

Comment: k, but this is also not working correctly or rather I would say perfectly as of flickr slideshow I edited the link in question

Comment: For the sake of the mess i can use condition based upon the time(date).  And what i want to implement is mousemove not mouseover as of flickr

Comment: Pls understand that i want to trigger these divs on the mousemove not on hovering anything as of flickr (see the link given in the question please) and for the mess or overload I edited the js in the question to use date

Comment: @knoxxs , Now I understand what you want. You're right, you **indeed need `mousemove` event**, see the updated answer.

Comment: You should try with `2000` instead of `300` in the line `if (date - prevDate > 300)`.
Anyway there is another big problem. You should have cleared and reset the `$('#up').delay(2000)` and `$('#down').delay(2000)` timers each time the `mouse move`s.
Other(un-)wise the `.slideUp('normal')` methods will be invoked 2 seconds after the mouse moved first time, no matter whether the mouse was moving or not within this 2 seconds of time period.

Comment: Now, don't ask me how to clear/reset those `.delay()` timers, because I don't know whether there is any way to do that in jQuery().

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture hover event rather than mousemove?

```
//divs show up on mouse move
$('#slides').hover(function(e) {
    $('#up').slideDown('fast',function (){
        $('#up').delay(1000).slideUp('fast');
    });
    $('#down').slideDown('fast',function (){
        $('#down').delay(1000).slideUp('fast');
    });
    }, function(e){});
});​
```

Comment: why? and that is also giving the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.mouseover()` instead. Have a look at the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3rZMM/6/

Comment: Is it because your CSS has #slides at 100% width?

Comment: thats why i used `mousemove`. What i want to implement is flickr kind of slideshow which triggers on the mousemove not on hovering anything